# vue chart js not showing in print preview

Tags: javascript, charts, vuejs2

hi i am using vue chartjs [link of npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chart-js) in my project.

the chart is working fine, but when i am trying to print a div where multiple charts are implement using the following code

```
let divContents = $("#exportDiv").html();
let printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Report</title>');
printWindow.document.write('<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" />');
printWindow.document.write('<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\" />');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
printWindow.document.write(divContents);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
printWindow.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){printWindow.print();},1000);
```

in preview window i am not seeing chart.

[image: screenshot of chart showing on the browser]

[image: screenshot of print preview]

Note: chart is not showing only when i am calling print on button click, if i am pressing ctrl+p chart is showing. but i want only a particular div to print so i cannot use ctrl+p.

what am i doing wrong?

i am declaring it

```
<vue-chart type="doughnut" :height="100" :options="optionsInvestorResearch" :data="chartInvestorResearch"></vue-chart>
```

and my optinons are

chartInvestorResearch: {},
optionsInvestorResearch: {

```
title: {
        display: false,
        fontsize: 14,
        text: 'Total de Pedidos por Situação'
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'right',
    },
},
```

update: i included my chart declaration and option.

Comment: maybe check your console for errors or warnings

Comment: @samayo no errors on page load or on print button click.

Comment: maybe it's your use of `document.write` you should never use that

Answer (score 0):

```
let divContents = $("#exportDiv").html();
```

this is your problem. 
Chart.js uses html5 canvas for its charts. So your divContents will only contain a canvas tag with nothing in it.

Try out `.toDataURL()`

Comment: thanks for your answer, and sorry for my late response... but i worked my way around and got it working, thanks again...

Comment: @rajesh what was your solution to this. Running into similar issuing

Comment: @overboard182 i have posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by first converting the chart to image when the animation completes and then i displayed the image in an image tag... and it appeared on the print preview screen...

first i created a div

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img id="url" />
    </div>
```

then i created a function

```
function done(){
    var url=chart.toBase64Image();
    document.getElementById("url").src=url;
}
```

then in my chart option

```
animation: {
    onComplete: done
},
```

it created an image of the chart and placed it in the the required div, in my case "url" then using css i made the the div containing chart hide and div containing chart image show.

Comment: @rajesh Thanks for updating this. Ended up coming up with my own solution as well, but this helped me :)

Comment: In case anyone is struggling to use toBase64Image() function in Vue while creating a component by extending a chart type, here is how to access the function 'this.$data._chart.toBase64Image()'